# How can I see related tag for a search query?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

When I search for a question, It is usefull to see which tags are related to my query. How can I see related tag to search query?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean by "related tag"?

Comment: Perhaps what he means is "how can I see the most common tags among my search results"?

Comment: @TimStone I mean what _Alain_ said. "how can I see the most common tags among my search result"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see your question here before I filed a feature request for exactly this.

But then I also went ahead and wrote a user script that implements the feature.

It works on Chrome, Opera, and Firefox at least under Windows 7. I haven't tested it with other OSes.

[See my answer on the feature request.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148866/154292)

I've now officially released this enhancement on Stackapps:

> [Script to add a “Related Tags” module for search on all Stack Exchange sites](https://stackapps.com/questions/3686)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best you can do at the moment is search all questions, and then skim the results to see what they are tagged with. For example, searching "firefox" will yield lots of questions containing the tags [firefox], [firefox-addon], [javascript], [browser], [add-on]... so you might consider those your 'search-related tags'.

*Aside*: When you click [Tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) and then do a search, it's only searching Tag names, not tag wikis. Maybe if those descriptions were included in the search too it would help satisfy that need.

Answer (score 0):

Search by tags.

[image]

Searches by tag show you related tags in the right sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

### Related Tags:

To my knowledge, clicking a tag is the only way to see related tags, which are listed in the right column, halfway down; for example, here's the tag for [java](/questions/tagged/java) on SO, and here's an example of what they look like:

[image]

### Grouping Related Tags:

Search wise, the only way to manually do this is by doing a tag search using more than one tag, for example: [[hello-world] + [java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello-world+java)